# predispatch on a adminthml controller

Tags: magento-1.7, php, event-observer, admin-controller

I am using magento 1.7. I would like to have a event before the call of this method `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController` save.

I tried to do it like this  :

Config.xml :

```
 <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch_sales_order_create_save>
                <observers>
                    <gfi_tnt_add_relay_quotes>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Gfi_TNT_Model_Observercontroller</class>
                        <method>addTntRelayQuote</method>
                    </gfi_tnt_add_relay_quotes>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_sales_order_create_save>
        </events>
</adminhtml>
```

`app/code/community/Gfi/TNT/Model/Observercontroller.php` :

```
class Gfi_TNT_Model_Observercontroller extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function addTntRelayQuote() {
     ........
    }
}
```

What is wrong in my code? Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake.
With the help of this post :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31468618/need-a-magento-event-that-will-fire-after-changing-the-shipping-address-of-an-or

I found what was wrong. The name on a controller event in the adminhtml is all the time like this :

```
<adminhtml>
        <events>
               <controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_...>
               </controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_...>
        </events>
</adminhtml>
```

I thought it was useless to add adminhtml before the path of my controller but not.

So in my case , my config.xml is :

```
 <adminhtml>
        <events>
                <controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_edit_save>
                    <observers>
                        <gfi_tnt_add_relay_quotesss>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>Gfi_TNT_Model_Observercontroller</class>
                            <method>addTntRelayQuote</method>
                        </gfi_tnt_add_relay_quotesss>
                    </observers>
                </controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_edit_save>
       </events>
</adminthtml>
```

I hope it can help :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to save some custom data after the order is saved from the backend

You can try this event

```
 <adminhtml>
    <events>
        <sales_order_save_after>
            <observers>
                <gfi_tnt_add_relay_quotes>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Gfi_TNT_Model_Observercontroller</class>
                    <method>addTntRelayQuote</method>
                </gfi_tnt_add_relay_quotes>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_after>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

**Observer**

```
<?php
class Gfi_TNT_Model_Observercontroller
{
    public function addTntRelayQuote() {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        // you can use this object and save your additional data
    }
}
```

You can also try `sales_order_save_before` event.

Comment: Indeed , i want to save some custom data on my order.
I have informations to save in my session. is it impossible to observer my controller method? 
But your code seems great , i will try it. Thank you